# Final webpack bundle always wraps functions inside eval irrespective of "devtool: 'inline-source-map'"

Tags: javascript, webpack, eval, bundling-and-minification

I was trying out different options for `devtool` in webpack and irrespective of the options set, it always wraps my components inside `eval` function.

**package.json** (I can provide full JSON on request)

```
"scripts": {
        "dev": "webpack -d --env dev --config ./webpack.dev.js && clientlib --verbose",
        "develop": "webpack -d --env dev --config ./webpack.dev.js",
        "prod": "webpack -p --config ./webpack.prod.js && clientlib --verbose",
        "start": "webpack-dev-server --open --config ./webpack.dev.js"
    },
```

**webpack.common.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const COMMON_SRC_DIR = __dirname + '/common.src';

module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    },
    entry: {
        common: COMMON_SRC_DIR + '/index.js',
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: [
                            '@babel/react',
                            '@babel/preset-env'
                        ],
                        plugins: [
                            "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
                            "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"
                          ]
                    },
                },
            },
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.LimitChunkCountPlugin({
            maxChunks: 1
        }),
    ],
    stats: {}
};
```

**webpack.dev.js**

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');

module.exports = merge(common, {
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
});
// I removed/commented out a lot of other options for debugging, but still, the generated bundle is being wrapped in the `eval` function.
```

**What is the expected behavior?**
Setting different options for `devtool` should generate different bundles.

**Other relevant information:**
webpack version:  `"^4.42.1"`
Node.js version: `v14.17.3`
Operating System: macOS Bug Sur

**A portion of output bundle**

```
"use strict";
eval("__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);\nvar commonComponents = ['SignIn', 'SearchBar', 'MiniCart', 'DropdownMenu', 'ProfileMegaMenu'];\n/* harmony default export */ __webpack_exports__[\"default\"] = (commonComponents);//# sourceURL=[module]\n//# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;charset=utf-8;base64,eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjozLCJmaWxlIjoiLi9hcHAuY29uZmlnLmpzLmpzIiwic291cmNlcyI6WyJ3ZWJwYWNrOi8vLy4vYXBwLmNvbmZpZy5qcz85NDg1Il0sInNvdXJjZXNDb250ZW50IjpbImNvbnN0IGNvbW1vbkNvbXBvbmVudHMgPSBbJ1NpZ25JbicsICdTZWFyY2hCYXInLCAnTWluaUNhcnQnLCAnRHJvcGRvd25NZW51JywgJ1Byb2ZpbGVNZWdhTWVudSddO1xuXG5leHBvcnQgZGVmYXVsdCBjb21tb25Db21wb25lbnRzO1xuIl0sIm1hcHBpbmdzIjoiQUFBQTtBQUFBO0FBRUEiLCJzb3VyY2VSb290IjoiIn0=\n//# sourceURL=webpack-internal:///./app.config.js\n");
```

Comment: The configuration looks fine. Do you mind setting up something for us to reproduce?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I have created a repo with the most minimal setup. It still wraps files inside eval. Starting to wonder if it has to do with one of the packages added into `package.json`. Here: https://github.com/thomsebastin/sample-wp-test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just figured out the option `-d --env dev` will override your configuration file that's why it possibly uses the default `devtool` mode.

I think you could just remove it and if you're keen to use env variables, you could use env plugin for `webpack`:

```js
// Remove this option `-d --env dev`
{
  "develop": "webpack --config ./webpack.dev.js",
}
```

Comment: Worked instantly. Thank you. I almost removed all packages from package.json without any luck. Sometimes a fresh set of eyes are needed to solve things.

Comment: Yeah that’s truth :)